# Creating a Pure function in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

I'm used to using Pure functions in Mathematica. How might I use them in R? For example:

Given a list of numbers, I want to assign TRUE/FALSE depending on whether the number is positive/negative.

```
z <- do.call(rnorm,list(n=10))            # Generate 10 numbers
f <- function(x) { x > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE } # Searching for proper syntax
b <- lapply(z,f)
```

Thanks

Comment: you can use `ifelse`   ? `f <- function(x) { ifelse(x > 0, TRUE, FALSE) }`. Actually, you don't need to use `lapply` here. Just run `ifelse(z > 0,TRUE,FALSE)` and it should give you the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Narrowly translated, your function would be:

```
f <- function(x) { if (x > 0)  TRUE else FALSE }
```

(you don't need to use `ifelse()` because this is a context in which `x` will be a scalar (i.e., a length-1 vector))

```
f <- function(x) { x > 0 }
```

would give the same result in your `lapply` call: so would

```
lapply(z,">",0)
```

As commented above you *could* use `ifelse(z>0,TRUE,FALSE)`.
But there's no need to specify logical return values, because the result of `z>0` is already a logical vector.  The idiomatic way to do this would be

```
z <- rnorm(10)   ## no need for do.call() in this example
z > 0
```

(logical comparison is vectorized in R)

Comment: lapply(z,f) works. Even though it seems to change the dimension from row to column vector. Why?

Comment: `lapply(z,f)` takes the *vector* `z` (1-dimensional: it's neither a row nor a column vector) and returns a *list*.  You can use `sapply()` (or `vapply()`) to get a vector back.

Answer (score 5):

Really easy:

```
b = z > 0
```

Most simple operations in R are already vectorized.